# How to install gnome-desktop or ubuntu-desktop in Lubuntu

Tags: gnome, lubuntu

I have installed `Lubuntu` 19.04 in my machine, lately. Now I want to install gnome-desktop environment. I have installed `ubuntu-desktop` using `synaptic package manager`. But it did not work out. May be I am missing something.

The output of `sudo lshw -short` is

```
H/W path               Device     Class          Description
============================================================
                                  system         TravelMate P243-M (TravelMate P243-M_069B_2_18)
/0                                bus            BA40_HC
/0/0                              memory         128KiB BIOS
/0/4                              processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz
/0/4/9                            memory         32KiB L1 cache
/0/4/a                            memory         256KiB L2 cache
/0/4/b                            memory         3MiB L3 cache
/0/8                              memory         32KiB L1 cache
/0/19                             memory         4GiB System Memory
/0/19/0                           memory         DIMM [empty]
/0/19/1                           memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
/0/100                            bridge         3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
/0/100/2                          display        3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
/0/100/14                         bus            7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/0            usb3       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/14/1            usb4       bus            xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/16                         communication  7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
/0/100/1a                         bus            7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
/0/100/1a/1            usb1       bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1a/1/1                     bus            Integrated Rate Matching Hub
/0/100/1a/1/1/1                   multimedia     HD WebCam
/0/100/1b                         multimedia     7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
/0/100/1c                         bridge         7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
/0/100/1c.2                       bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3
/0/100/1c.2/0                     generic        RTL8411 PCI Express Card Reader
/0/100/1c.2/0.2        enp4s0f2   network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1c.7                       bridge         7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8
/0/100/1c.7/0          wlp9s0     network        BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
/0/100/1d                         bus            7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
/0/100/1d/1            usb2       bus            EHCI Host Controller
/0/100/1d/1/1                     bus            Integrated Rate Matching Hub
/0/100/1f                         bridge         HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller
/0/100/1f.2            scsi0      storage        7 Series Chipset Family 4-port SATA Controller [IDE mode]
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0      /dev/sda   disk           500GB HGST HTS725050A7
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0/3    /dev/sda3  volume         318GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0/4    /dev/sda4  volume         146GiB Windows NTFS volume
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0/4/5  /dev/sda5  volume         7825MiB Linux swap volume
/0/100/1f.2/0.0.0/4/6  /dev/sda6  volume         139GiB EXT4 volume
/0/100/1f.3                       bus            7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller
/0/100/1f.5                       storage        7 Series Chipset Family 2-port SATA Controller [IDE mode]
/0/1                              system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/2                              system         PnP device PNP0b00
/0/3                              generic        PnP device INT3f0d
/0/5                              input          PnP device PNP0303
/0/6                              generic        PnP device SYN1b20
/0/7                              system         PnP device PNP0c02
/0/9                              system         PnP device PNP0c01
/1                     lxcbr0     network        Ethernet interface
```

The output of `sudo lshw -C video` is

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:30 memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Meanwhile, I have installed `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` through

```
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`
```

Comment: Did you logout, and switch to the Ubuntu desktop??  My box has LXQt (Lubuntu), XFCE (Xubuntu), MATE (Ubuntu-MATE) & GNOME (Ubuntu) installed and I select which I use at login; it's default is the whatever I used last time.

Comment: You didn't mention your version; eg. `ubuntu-desktop` will grab the Unity 7 desktop if your release is 16.04 LTS as it was the default for 16.04

Comment: @guiverc When I do that, scree becomes black and unresponsive.

Comment: You may need to provide details of your hardware (eg. cpu architecture, ram, video details for example `sudo lshw -C video` which lists hardware of class video; the first will likely be x86_64 but ram I'm guessing you know).  GNOME has higher hardware specs than the LXQt desktop has (eg. ram on your video card - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements but note 19.04 & GNOME have higher requirements than listed there for minimum as it still covers Unity (16.04 desktop); there is a better page but I can't find it currently)

Comment: @guiverc updated my question.